# "Error in query (1030): Got error 168 from storage engine" when creating table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to create a table on a separate directory, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `abcdef` (
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DATA DIRECTORY='/media/sdc/mysql/';
```

But it returns the error:

> Error in query (1030): Got error 168 from storage engine

In the log it says:

```
2018-09-17T09:43:22.412636Z 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2018-09-17T09:43:22.412686Z 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
```

The directory `/media/sdc/mysql/` exists and I ran the following commands already:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /media/sdc/mysql
chmod -R 777 /media/sdc/mysql
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.

I have another server running MySQL 5.6 where I created the same table with no issue. In fact I'm replicating it on a new upgraded server.

So why can't MySQL use `/media/sdc/mysql`?

Comment: Does mysqld can access /media/ and /media/sdc/ for reading at least?

Comment: On both servers (working and not working), /media and /media/sdc belong to root.

Comment: selinux/  apparmor?

Comment: What account the mysqld is running of? is it `mysql`?

Comment: @danblack you are right, it was apparmor, it's working now. If you submit a reply I will accept it.

Comment: good. hoping it was for your sake. Can now drop the 777 down to 755.

Comment: 755 should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[apparmor](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/apparmor-and-mysql) (and [selinux](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/selinux-and-mysql)) provide additional access controls beyond permissions that can cause these permission denied (13) errors. This occurs generally on systems where data or log files differ from the default.

With apparmor you would add to the bottom of `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld`:

```
/media/sdc/mysql/ r,
/media/sdc/mysql/** rwk,
```

And then reload the apparmor service:

```
service apparmor reload
```

If it was selinux:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/media/sdc/mysql(/.*)?"
restorecon -Rv /media/sdc/mysql
```