# apparmor prevents mysql from starting

Tags: mysql

I am trying to start `mysql 5.5` service on `ubuntu 14.04` but it fails.

I noticed in `dmesg` the following error:

```
[ 1201.519101] init: mysql post-start process (22140) terminated with status 1
[ 1201.539004] init: mysql main process (22165) terminated with status 1
[ 1201.539016] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
[ 1201.542554] init: mysql post-start process (22166) terminated with status 1
[ 1201.562121] init: mysql main process (22196) terminated with status 1
[ 1201.562134] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

How can I address this?

I recently made some changes to `my.cnf` to `innodb` - related configuration in case if this is causing the issue:

```
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
innodb_read_io_threads          = 16
innodb_write_io_threads         = 16  #To stress the double write buffer
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 28000M
# innodb_log_file_size          = 256M #Small log files, more page flush
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
# innodb_log_buffer_size            = 512M
innodb_flush_method         = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit      = 0
innodb_file_format          = BARRACUDA
# innodb_log_file_size          = 512M
```

Comment: This workaround may help: Stop and disable the apparmor - sudo service apparmor stop and sudo update-rc.d -f apparmor remove, now mysql should work.

Answer (score 1):

Search the web for

```
mysql apparmor
```

There are lots of solutions out there.  A couple of possibilities:
https://askubuntu.com/a/953988
https://serverfault.com/questions/896653/how-do-i-get-the-right-apparmor-profile-for-mysql-on-ubuntu

You should not need to disable or remove apparmor

Comment: or [oracle blog - AppArmor and MySQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/apparmor-and-mysql), or [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217776/error-in-query-1030-got-error-168-from-storage-engine-when-creating-table/217843#217843)