# How to start second MySQL instance on boot on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, instance, startup

I have a second MySQL 8 instance running on Ubunut 20.04, started by this command:

```
mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/home/user/mysqld_replica.cnf &
```

The config file contains all needed settings like port, socket and data dir. That works well but I can not figure out how to start the second instance on boot.

What would be the recommended way to start both instances at boot time?

Answer (score 0):

Copy `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` to `/etc/systemd/system/mysql_replica.service`.

In the copied service file add `--defaults-file=/home/user/mysqld_replica.cnf` to the `ExecStart*` directives as the first argument to `mysqld`.

Reload systemd to read this `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Start the service `systemctl start mysql_replica.service`.

Enable on boot with `systemctl enable mysql_replica.service`.

You many need a few quick apparmor fixes [like this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220712/apparmor-prevents-mysql-from-starting) to enable writing on your second data directory.