# The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable even with full permissions set

Tags: mysql, mysqld

i'm trying to change the datadir in mysql, i created a new directory with the user mysql as a owner, i know am not supposed to set the permission to 777. but even with this full permission still getting the same error in the log file whenever i try to start the mysql service.

`[InnoDB] The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable`

```
user@user:~$ ls -l /database2/mysql | grep ibdata1 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 12582912 Jan 15 15:24 ibdata1
```

any solution ?

Comment: Are `/database2`  and `/database2/mysql` accessible to the mysql user?

Comment: @mustaccio yes, both are owned by the mysql user.

Comment: And both directories are at least `dr-x------`?

Comment: @RickJames yes, ```drwxr-xr-x   3 mysql mysql  4096 Jan 15 17:10 database2```

Comment: @Someone - What OS?  Is `/database2` mounted?  Is SELINUX in effect?

Comment: @RickJames, SELinux?, /database2 is not mounted.

Comment: Or [apparmor](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217776/error-in-query-1030-got-error-168-from-storage-engine-when-creating-table/217843#217843). What OS/Distro?  (e.g. Debian/Fedora/Ubuntu..)

Comment: @danblack  ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/selinux-and-mysql-v2) and getting a main idea about SELinux and Apparmor i have finally managed to solve the issue.
The solution was adding the new path of my new `datadir` in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` like this:

```
/database2/ r,
/database2/** rwk,
```

Now restart the apparmor service and start the mysql service.

```
sudo systemctl restart apparmor
sudo systemclt start mysql
```